How to fix distorted UV?
I'm trying to unwrap character and getting distorted uv:

I've tried to scale/rotate/move it, but connected parts just follows it:

I've tried to unpin it, but without any results. What am I doing wrong? Why does only one part of uv can be so stretched?
P.S. Can't share blend file or give closer look because of NSFW.

Have you marked some seams on your model before trying to unwrap it and why have you pinned it?

"I've tried to scale/rotate/move it, but connected parts just follows it:" The reason the connected vertices follow is because you have "UV Sync" enabled! The UV Sync option is the second icon, top left corner of the UV editor. The very first icon top left that is highlighted in blue in your screenshots.

@JohnEason Aren't the red lines usually the seams? So I guess he has marked some seams.

It does look a bit like it. They seem to be in strange places though, particularly the head, and I'm not sure why he's talking about unpinning it, unless he means the UV Sync option that 3fingeredfrog mentions.

@3fingeredfrog when I disabled "UV Sync" the problem with movement/rotation was solved, thank you! Do you know what should cause this distortion? Why does one side of body is good, but another side is stretched?

@JohnEason Yes, I've marked some seems. Maybe that seams in strange places, but I have a reason for that - I'm trying to adapt uv to common character's textures, where we have main body, face, hands and legs. Like this

"Do you know what should cause this distortion?"
Assuming you have non of the vertices of the torso part of the character "pinned" in the UV editor, that's to say you have none of the torso vertices coloured red then it could be a simple as having the wrong options selected in the UV Unwrap Last operator panel.
In the 3D viewport > Edit mode, Face selection mode enabled, select the torso, L key, then open the UV menu and choose the Unwrap option. Now open the Last operator panel, (bottom left corner of 3D viewport) and check which method you have selected, Angle Based or Conformal and whether of not you have Fill Holes checked. My guess is you should have Angle Based and Fill Holes checked for a symmetrical UV unwrap, but you need to experiment to see which is best for you.
In the examples below I have unwrapped the Blender monkey head, notice how changing the options effect how the head is unwrapped:



IF the above hasn't solved your issue then you could try the following, (me using the monkey head as an example):
1: In the UV editor, Island selection mode, select the distorted UV island and rotate it until it is approximately correctly aligned horizontally.
2: then in Edge selection mode select the very middle line of vertices that run down the middle of the front of the torso.

3: With these vertices still selected right click in the UV editor to open the UV context menu and choose the Straighten X option. This should straighten the vertices along the X axis as in the screenshot below.
4: Next use the P key to Pin these vertices in place so that they will not move when we next UV unwrap the monkey head and hopefully all the other vertices to the left and right of these pinned vertices will unwrap symmetrically:

5: Still in the UV editor, select all the vertices A key then U key to open the UV menu and select the Unwrap option. With a little luck even with Fill Holes left unchecked we have a a symmetrical UV unwrap:


First, select your entire mesh, then in edit mode, press U then click Smart UV Project to unwrap it properly.

I'd be glad if it was that easy. Unfortunately, tre result is awful.
